# Django1.7 : 'list' object is not callable

Tags: python, django, list, python-2.7, django-1.7

I'm getting 'list' object is not callable.

My models.py

```
class KeyValues(models.Model):
    value=models.IntegerField(max_length=1,blank=True)

class Key(models.Model):
        position=models.IntegerField(max_length=1,default=0,blank=True)
        keyValues= key=models.ManyToManyField(KeyValues)

class FileDetails(models.Model):
    fileId = models.CharField(max_length = 100,primary_key=True,db_index=True)
    key=models.ManyToManyField(Key)
```

My code :

```
def Arrangement(fileid,key,user):
    Key=[]
    NewKey=[]
    Key[:0]=key

    length=len(key)
    for i in range (0,length):
        NewKey.append(str(ord(key[i])%5)) 
        pos=int(ord(key[i])%5)


        key_values=KeyValues(value=key[i])
        key_values.save()
        KeY=Key(position=pos)
        KeY.save()
        KeY.keyValues.add(key_values)
    KeY.save()
    filedetails=FileDetails.objects.get(fileId=fileid)
    filedetails.key.add(KeY)
    filedetails.save()
```

I'm getting 'list' object is not callable at

> KeY=Key(position=pos)

Why i'm getting such an error ? How can i correct it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You initialized a list named `Key`, and you also have a class named `Key`. Rename the `Key` variable in the first line in your `Arrangement` method to something else.

Your naming conventions is very confusing, by the way. Try to follow [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) or at least name your variables in lowercase.